# Golang use array values in db query to filter records

Tags: go, goquery, go-structtag

I have list of array int64 values

```
ids = [{1} {2} {3}]
```

I want to use the above array in db query to filter out the records where ID is not in above ids.

```
SELECT * from table where id not in (1,2,3);
```

I tried many ways to do but failing to make the query string.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you trying to solve the problem? and provide a valid syntax like  `ids :=  []int{1,2,3}`

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample scenario as follows :

```
func main() {
    ids := []int{1, 2, 3}

    var tmp []string

    for _, v := range ids {
        tmp = append(tmp, fmt.Sprint(v))
    }

    query := "SELECT * from table where id not in (" + strings.Join(tmp, ",") + ")"
    fmt.Println(query)

}
```

OR

You can run it in go playground [link](https://go.dev/play/p/2Y-zWRE_roR)